# Connection refused in email application

Tags: python, email

I am making WEB application send email.I wrote codes,

```
def mail(self,mail_adress, docx):

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'TEST' 
    msg['From'] = 'info@xxx.com'  
    msg['To'] = mail_adress 

    body = "TEST"
    body = MIMEText(body)
    msg.attach(body)

    mine = {'type': 'text', 'subtype': 'docx'}
    attachment = MIMEBase(mine['type'], mine['subtype'])

    name = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__name__))

    attach_file = {'name': 'test.docx', 'path': name  + "/" + docx}
    file = open(attach_file['path'], 'rb')
    attachment.set_payload(file.read())
    file.close()
    encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
    msg.attach(attachment)
    attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=attach_file['name'])

    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.connect()
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.send_message(msg,mail_adress)
    server.quit()
```

When I run it,
[Errno 111] Connection refused error happens.I really cannot understand why such an error happens.How should I fix this?

Comment: If you're using gmail, you need to let Gmail know that allowing "less secure apps" to access your gmail account.

Comment: @greentec I do not use gmail

Comment: Do you actually have an SMTP Server listening on port 25 on that machine? Using [`connect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.connect) without any arguments, will make it try to connect to a mail server on the default `localhost:25`. If no service is listening on that socket, the connection refused error is to be expected.